# Navigation popBackStack disables further navigation to this Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-jetpack, android-navigation

I am loading a Fragment while using `Navigation` component with this code and it works.

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.menu_nav_graph, bundleOf("menuItem" to item))
```

I want to close the Fragment on button click and I use this code for that

```
findNavController().popBackStack()
```

The app navigates to the previous fragment but when I try to navigate to the popped Fragment destination again with the code above the app reaches the code and nothing happens. The Fragment is not loading. So the navigation code is executed but the Fragment is not opening. The same happens when instead of using `popBackStack` I use this with the onClick listener

```
activity?.onBackPressed()
```

Same effect, the app reaches the navigation line, no crash, no exception is thrown, it just doesn't open the Fragment.

At the same time, my back arrow navigation is working and it does go to the same destination multiple times after pressing back from the Fragment. This confuses me as I am using the same code in `onOptionsItemSelected`and it works, so I don't understand what makes it different when I just call `onBackPressed()` on button click.

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean =
        when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                activity?.onBackPressed()
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
```

**How to close a Fragment on button click and be able to navigate to the same destination consequently?**

Comment: you mean `findNavController().navigate(R.id.menu_nav_graph, bundleOf("menuItem" to item))` not working after it back from previous fragment?

Comment: yes, exactly what I mean, it works only for the first navigation action, and when you back off it it won't again

Answer (score 5):

After debugging more I found out the root cause, the issue is not with the `navigation` not executing navigation but I guess with `Fragment` lifecycle in the `navigation` library implementation. The `Fragment` was not destroyed when backing off and the `onBackPressed` was triggered right after navigating to the same destination again.

To trigger `onBackPressed` I am using `LiveData` pushing this command from `ViewModel`. When returning to the `Fragment` the same command was pushed again to `LiveData` and the navigation back was triggered again so it appeared that no navigation was happening.

The solution was implementing `SingleLiveEvent` `LiveData`. It was pushing the value only once.

Here is the link to the implementation https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java